# How to concat 2 vars with tags in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just have a 2 vars witch contains html tags and I want to concat them, I tried concat also + but strange it doesnt work.

```
function html_with_category(){  
     var html_with_category = $('<div id="q_section" style="display:none</div>'); 
return html_with_category;  
     }

function html_without_category(){
    var html_without_category = $('<div class="q_rt_rowcell-1-title"></div></div><div class="om"></div>'); 
  return html_without_category; 
    }
 function html_last_div(){
       var html_last_div = $('</div></div></div></div>'); 
     return html_last_div;  
    }


var html_with_cat =  html_with_category();
var html_without_cat =  html_without_category(); 
var html_last_d = html_last_div();
```

And I want to receive a var

```
 var concatdivs = html_with_cat + "" + html_last_d;
```

and concatdivs to look like

```
<div class="q_rt_rowcell-1-title"></div></div><div class="om"></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work ? what's the error ?

Comment: I try to append this var(div) to another block and here is write that var concatdivs = $(html_with_category + html_last_div);
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object][object Object]

Comment: Did you try var concatdivs = html_with_cat.append(html_last_d) ?

Answer (score 4):

When you pass a string of HTML to jQuery, it converts it into a DOM.

It doesn't wrap a jQuery object around a string of raw HTML, it turns the HTML into elements first.

Consequently, you cannot create a jQuery object with a div start tag in it, create another jQuery object with a div end tag in it, and then join them up.

You must pass something resembling well-formed markup in.

If you want to concatenate strings of HTML (which I'd generally recommend against as it usually ends up being more complicated then dealing with a DOM tree) then you need to **keep them as strings** until you have finished concatenating (then you can pass the final string through jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have HTML code in the variables, you have used the `$()` function to parse the code into DOM elements, which are contained in jQuery objects.

If you don't parse the strings into elements but keep them as strings, you can easily concatenate the HTML code:

```
function html_with_category(){  
  var html_with_category = '<div id="q_section" style="display:none</div>'; 
  return html_with_category;  
}

function html_without_category(){
  var html_without_category = '<div class="q_rt_rowcell-1-title"></div></div><div class="om"></div>';
  return html_without_category; 
}

function html_last_div(){
  var html_last_div = '</div></div></div></div>';
  return html_last_div;
}

var html_with_cat = html_with_category();
var html_without_cat = html_without_category(); 
var html_last_d = html_last_div();

var concatdivs = html_with_cat + html_last_d;
```

If you want the result as elements, you can do that after concatenating the strings:

```
var concatdivs = $(html_with_cat + html_last_d);
```

Note: You should check the syntax of the HTML code in the strings. You are missing an end quote for the `style` attribute and a closing `>` in the first string. In the second and third string the starting and ending tags doesn't add up. Before turning the code into elements the tags have to match up to complete elements, otherwise you won't get the result that you expect.